Elastic search trained model inference not working
After importing the text embedding sentence-transformers/msmarco-MiniLM-L12-cos-v5 model to elasticsearch using eland the model infering doesnt work.
eland command:
eland_import_hub_model --url http://localhost:9200 --hub-model-id sentence-transformers/msmarco-MiniLM-L-12-v3 --task-type text_embedding --start
Infer request:
POST /_ml/trained_models/sentence-transformers__msmarco-minilm-l12-cos-v5/deployment/_infer
{
  "docs": {
    "text_field": "How is the weather in Jamaica?"
  }
}

Error:
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "status_exception",
                "reason": "Error in inference process: [inference canceled as process is stopping]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "status_exception",
        "reason": "Error in inference process: [inference canceled as process is stopping]"
    },
    "status": 500
}

Docker logs of all the processes
2024-05-16 14:47:29 {"@timestamp":"2024-05-16T12:47:29.207Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"[sentence-transformers__msmarco-minilm-l12-cos-v5] Starting model deployment of model [sentence-transformers__msmarco-minilm-l12-cos-v5]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[f059c181c171][ml_utility][T#3]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.inference.deployment.DeploymentManager","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"eEqzvIFnQx6Lt08J4545wQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"-It6EisaTT2HVi05RqZGdA","elasticsearch.node.name":"f059c181c171","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
2024-05-16 14:47:55 {"@timestamp":"2024-05-16T12:47:55.102Z", "log.level": "WARN",  "data_stream.dataset":"deprecation.elasticsearch","data_stream.namespace":"default","data_stream.type":"logs","elasticsearch.event.category":"api","event.code":"deprecated_route_POST_/_ml/trained_models/{model_id}/deployment/_infer","message":"[POST /_ml/trained_models/{model_id}/deployment/_infer] is deprecated! Use [POST /_ml/trained_models/{model_id}/_infer] instead." , "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"deprecation.elasticsearch","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[f059c181c171][transport_worker][T#4]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.deprecation.rest.RestController","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"eEqzvIFnQx6Lt08J4545wQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"-It6EisaTT2HVi05RqZGdA","elasticsearch.node.name":"f059c181c171","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
2024-05-16 14:47:55 {"@timestamp":"2024-05-16T12:47:55.413Z", "log.level":"ERROR", "message":"[sentence-transformers__msmarco-minilm-l12-cos-v5] pytorch_inference/336 process stopped unexpectedly: Fatal error: 'si_signo 11, si_code: 1, si_errno: 0, address: 0xffffb27ca140, library: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6, base: 0xffffb26bd000, normalized address: 0x10d140', version: 8.13.4 (build 8480947324d752)\n", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[f059c181c171][ml_native_inference_comms][T#4]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.process.AbstractNativeProcess","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"eEqzvIFnQx6Lt08J4545wQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"-It6EisaTT2HVi05RqZGdA","elasticsearch.node.name":"f059c181c171","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
2024-05-16 14:47:55 {"@timestamp":"2024-05-16T12:47:55.414Z", "log.level":"ERROR", "message":"[sentence-transformers__msmarco-minilm-l12-cos-v5] inference process crashed due to reason [[sentence-transformers__msmarco-minilm-l12-cos-v5] pytorch_inference/336 process stopped unexpectedly: Fatal error: 'si_signo 11, si_code: 1, si_errno: 0, address: 0xffffb27ca140, library: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6, base: 0xffffb26bd000, normalized address: 0x10d140', version: 8.13.4 (build 8480947324d752)\n]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[f059c181c171][ml_native_inference_comms][T#4]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.inference.deployment.DeploymentManager","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"eEqzvIFnQx6Lt08J4545wQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"-It6EisaTT2HVi05RqZGdA","elasticsearch.node.name":"f059c181c171","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
2024-05-16 14:47:55 {"@timestamp":"2024-05-16T12:47:55.414Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"Inference process [sentence-transformers__msmarco-minilm-l12-cos-v5] failed due to [[sentence-transformers__msmarco-minilm-l12-cos-v5] pytorch_inference/336 process stopped unexpectedly: Fatal error: 'si_signo 11, si_code: 1, si_errno: 0, address: 0xffffb27ca140, library: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6, base: 0xffffb26bd000, normalized address: 0x10d140', version: 8.13.4 (build 8480947324d752)\n]. This is the [1] failure in 24 hours, and the process will be restarted.", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[f059c181c171][ml_native_inference_comms][T#4]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.inference.deployment.DeploymentManager","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"eEqzvIFnQx6Lt08J4545wQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"-It6EisaTT2HVi05RqZGdA","elasticsearch.node.name":"f059c181c171","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
2024-05-16 14:47:55 {"@timestamp":"2024-05-16T12:47:55.414Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"[sentence-transformers__msmarco-minilm-l12-cos-v5] Starting model deployment of model [sentence-transformers__msmarco-minilm-l12-cos-v5]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[f059c181c171][ml_native_inference_comms][T#4]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.inference.deployment.DeploymentManager","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"eEqzvIFnQx6Lt08J4545wQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"-It6EisaTT2HVi05RqZGdA","elasticsearch.node.name":"f059c181c171","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
2024-05-16 14:47:55 {"@timestamp":"2024-05-16T12:47:55.414Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"path: /_ml/trained_models/sentence-transformers__msmarco-minilm-l12-cos-v5/deployment/_infer, params: {model_id=sentence-transformers__msmarco-minilm-l12-cos-v5}, status: 500", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[f059c181c171][ml_native_inference_comms][T#5]","log.logger":"rest.suppressed","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"eEqzvIFnQx6Lt08J4545wQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"-It6EisaTT2HVi05RqZGdA","elasticsearch.node.name":"f059c181c171","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch","error.type":"org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException","error.message":"Error in inference process: [inference canceled as process is stopping]","error.stack_trace":"org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Error in inference process: [inference canceled as process is stopping]\n\tat org.elasticsearch.ml@8.13.4/org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.inference.deployment.AbstractPyTorchAction.onFailure(AbstractPyTorchAction.java:114)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.ml@8.13.4/org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.inference.deployment.InferencePyTorchAction.processResult(InferencePyTorchAction.java:182)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.ml@8.13.4/org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.inference.deployment.InferencePyTorchAction.lambda$doRun$3(InferencePyTorchAction.java:151)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.13.4/org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$2.onResponse(ActionListener.java:171)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.ml@8.13.4/org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.inference.pytorch.process.PyTorchResultProcessor.lambda$notifyAndClearPendingResults$3(PyTorchResultProcessor.java:145)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.forEach(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1603)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.ml@8.13.4/org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.inference.pytorch.process.PyTorchResultProcessor.notifyAndClearPendingResults(PyTorchResultProcessor.java:144)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.ml@8.13.4/org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.inference.pytorch.process.PyTorchResultProcessor.process(PyTorchResultProcessor.java:137)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.ml@8.13.4/org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.inference.deployment.DeploymentManager.lambda$startDeployment$2(DeploymentManager.java:180)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.13.4/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:917)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)\n"}
2024-05-16 14:48:00 {"@timestamp":"2024-05-16T12:48:00.161Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"[.ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2024.05.16-000001] creating index, cause [initialize_data_stream], templates [.deprecation-indexing-template], shards [1]/[1]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[f059c181c171][masterService#updateTask][T#8]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetadataCreateIndexService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"eEqzvIFnQx6Lt08J4545wQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"-It6EisaTT2HVi05RqZGdA","elasticsearch.node.name":"f059c181c171","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}
2024-05-16 14:48:00 {"@timestamp":"2024-05-16T12:48:00.167Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"adding data stream [.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default] with write index [.ds-.logs-deprecation.elasticsearch-default-2024.05.16-000001], backing indices [], and aliases []", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[f059c181c171][masterService#updateTask][T#8]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetadataCreateDataStreamService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"eEqzvIFnQx6Lt08J4545wQ","elasticsearch.node.id":"-It6EisaTT2HVi05RqZGdA","elasticsearch.node.name":"f059c181c171","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch"}


Having the same issue with the latest version of Eland and Elasticsearch. Using Eland version 8.12.1 and a previous version of Elasticsearch everything works fine but upgrading to the latest version of both and I am hitting the above issue.
